# How to call SOAP method from ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, soap, wsdl, asp.net-core-8

My ASP.NET Core 8 application in C# has Web API controller. This controller should invoke a SOAP method using https.

WSDL of SOAP server is available in https://ncfailid.emta.ee/index.php/s/wTKjgm9QQnWLZEH/download/tor.wsdl.txt

Method `TOOTREG` which should called is defined in it as

```
  <element name="TOOTREG">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="request" type="tns:tootregRequestType"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
  <element name="TOOTREGResponse">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="request" type="tns:tootregRequestType"/>
        <element name="response" type="tns:tootregResponseType"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
```

Request body `tns:tootregRequestType` in complex type defined in this file. Response is also complex type.

How to call a SOAP method in C# from the API controller?

Can .NET code be generated from the WSDL, or should the XML request be created and posted manually and response parsed using xml parser?

I tried in Visual Studio Community edition to use "Add Service Reference" contextmenu , but got errors:

```
The optional WSDL extension element 'address' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:service[@name='TorServiceV6']/wsdl:port[@name='TorV6WebServiceImpl']
The optional WSDL extension element 'title' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:service[@name='TorServiceV6']/wsdl:port[@name='TorV6WebServiceImpl']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORTI']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORSPORT']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORT']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORRKA']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORINFO']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORIK']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TOOTREG']
The optional WSDL extension element 'requirecontent' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TOOTREG_AMETNIK']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TOOTREG_AMETNIK']
The optional WSDL extension element 'requirecontent' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORRGNO']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORRGNO']
The optional WSDL extension element 'requirecontent' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORSYNK']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORSYNK']
The optional WSDL extension element 'requirecontent' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORKODAK']
The optional WSDL extension element 'version' from namespace 'http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd' was not handled.\r\nXPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://emta-v6.x-road.eu']/wsdl:binding[@name='TorPortBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='TORKODAK']
There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:\r\n    Source: \r\n    Line: 13 Column: 3\r\n   Validation Error: The attributeGroup 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:specialAttrs' has already been declared.
There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:\r\n    Source: \r\n    Line: 12 Column: 3\r\n   Validation Error: The global attribute 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:id' has already been declared.
There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:\r\n    Source: \r\n    Line: 11 Column: 3\r\n   Validation Error: The global attribute 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:base' has already been declared.
There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:\r\n    Source: \r\n    Line: 3 Column: 3\r\n   Validation Error: The global attribute 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:space' has already been declared.
There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:\r\n    Source: \r\n    Line: 2 Column: 3\r\n   Validation Error: The global attribute 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' has already been declared.
```

How to fix those erros?

Comment: Yes, based on my testing , we could still generate the codes by using the add reference.

Comment: I tried it but got errors. I updated question and added errors occured.